# Is there any way to make a Excel file without FAT format (in RL-ARM libraries)?

Tags: c, networking, keil, lpc

I made a web service in LPC 1768 and I also have 2Mb Flash storage in my board (IC is AT45db160),which, I used it for saving variables. Now I want to return all variables in Flash as an Excel file.

I used a SD card for my FTP unit. compiler is KEIL (implemented by RL-ARM). board designed by my company which includes a USB device, Ethernet port, Flash IC and SD card slot.

Comment: The question is not very specific. What do you mean be "return all variables"? What do you have in flash, what do you want to get in Excel? How are the variables stored? Do you have a list of them, ... Please provide way more information about your problem.

Comment: thank you. Variables are Regulatory parameters . I want user can download them as a file and after that user set those parameter for other devices and I also stored variables without any format.

Comment: That does not explain anythine more than in the question. Are they values in memory, values in some flash file system? Show (not describe) some examples about what you have and what you want to get.

Comment: The values are in Flash and Micro's RAM . I want my device parameters (Adjustable values like Modbus addresses and user password etc.) can report for them as a file(able downloaded via my web service) . this's it.

Comment: If I get that correctly, you have some values spread all over your memory and want to collect them into a EXCEL file. That sounds like a lot of different little tasks: Collect all the values, (get a list of the values to start with), create a Excel file (in memory or on SDCard), provide that file to the user (via FTP?). That is way too broad for a single question on SO. You should split it accordingly and address each task separately in a new question per topic.

Comment: you almost understand but I don't want to create the file in SDCARD , I want to collect them in External Flash (AT45db160) and after that , I send the file for client through web service . the main question is how can I make a file in my External Flash with FAT format by the way , I used of External Flash for other values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238724/discussion-between-milad-and-gerhardh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have a storage in RAM or FLASH . for more information read up [it](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/rlarm/rlarm_tn_creat_webpg_ram.htm)
[image]
and after that I can make a file in FLASH for creating report file.